# oauth2 with curl in two steps

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

For accessing Microsofts CRM dynamics.com I guess I need two curl requests:

a) one for the authorization code and
b) one to get the one-hour access token to receive/send data

a) `curl -X POST -d grant_type=password&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyyyy&username=email@email.com&password=zzzzz&redirect_uri=https://xyz&scope=read.org" https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize&resource=https://uuuuuuuuu.crm4.dynamics.com`

b) `curl -X POST -d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=xxx&code=ttttttttt" https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token`

a) is working but b NOT, it says always no grant_type :/

Thanks a lot in advance and best
Robert

Answer (score 0):

The password grant only requires a single request, to the token endpoint - no authorization code is used.

Note that the authorization endpoint is designed to be used for interactive OAuth redirects from user browsers.

So it looks like you'll be able to fix your problem just by changing Step A to use the token endpoint. See also [this link](https://nishantrana.me/2019/08/23/connect-to-dynamics-365-web-api-using-oauth-2-0-resource-owner-password-credential-ropc/) for a worked example.

Comment: Hi, I received an bearer with "token" in the URL but then I get a 401 not authorized when trying to receive data. With Postman, "authorize" in URL, grant_type = implicit I get a working token :/

Comment: Maybe compare the access token / JWT contents by pasting them into in an online tool such as [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools) to see what is different - in particular the issuer / audience / scopes fields.